# \n automatically add on array Values after converting AnyObject to String?

Tags: swift, foundation

I am trying to append AnyObject type Values on my `arr`. but when first i convert `AnyObject` to `String` it automatically add \n with every values?
I did't want to change `arr` type and structure. Can anyone please tell me what i do??
Thanks

```
var arr : [(String, String)] = [("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKZKl7Bgu0","6.jpg"),
                                  ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SYlLi5djz0","7.jpg")]

var url : [String] = []
var image : [String] = []

for i in arr{

  url.append(i.0)
  image.append(i.1)
  print("URL values.............. \(url)")
  print("Image values.............. \(image)")
}

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(url, forKey: "u")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(image, forKey: "i")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

let u = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("u")! //as! String
let i = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("i")!

print("U Values   \(u)")
print("I values   \(i)")

// let tup = ("\(u)", "\(i)")
let tup = (String(u),String(i))
print("tup Values \(tup)")
arr.removeAll()
arr.append(tup)
print("arr Values    \(arr)")
```

[Output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxS0twV0VRbUhCMms)

Comment: Your `[(String, String)]` Array is called `tuple`. A bit misleading, no?

Comment: But when i print after  arr Initialization it not show \n on output `[("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKZKl7Bgu0", "6.jpg"), ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SYlLi5djz0", "7.jpg")]`

Comment: When i use this `Array` in `CollectionViewCell` after initialization, CollectionViewCell show link and image perfectly but when i use it in CollectionViewCell after `arr.append(tup)` nothing display?

Comment: I've made an answer to your original question. If you have a new, different question, *ask a new question* (make a new post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` adds the newlines: your objects are unchanged, there's no "\n" added anywhere, this is only in the printed representation.

It doesn't add the newline when you print the objects after having declared them, because their type is known (String), so `print` just prints the Strings correctly without having to guess.

But after you get your values back from `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey` their type is `AnyObject`, so `print` behaves entirely differently.